# image path in ng file upload in angular

Tags: angularjs

After uploading the image using `ng-file-upload` to `https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload`

,I get in response only the image name.

Now, if I want to render the image in html

```
 <img ng-show="createRecipeForm.file.$valid" src="{{response.filename}}" class="img-rounded"  height="100">
```

or

```
 <img ng-show="createRecipeForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="{{imageArray[$index]}}" class="img-rounded"  height="100">
```

How do I get my image here? I am using this for demo purpose and need to get it from my local computer only for now.

I see can not give path to a drive on computer here for `src`.

So, how do I render the image in html given that I have the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the file using a web server, you should have access to the relative path of the server to use before `filename` in `src="{{response.filename}}"`

Check where in the folder structure you are storing them, then you can try: (e.g.)

```
src="/AppData/{{response.filename}}"
```

Comment: But what if I do not want to save the file anywhere and just hold it in scope against a ng-model, save in an array on upload and then rende from that array? Is that posible?

Comment: The file needs to be stored somewhere. Angular itself won't store a thing, the browser may do it, but this storage is limited.